# Florist bouqets of six flowers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

**A florist is tying up bouquets of six flowers. The florist has ten white roses, ten orange roses, seven lillies, six tulips, four alstromerias and nine hyacinths at her disposal. How many different bouquets can she tie?**

*I tried to solve but i can not find the solution. I think order is not important and there is no difference 10 white or 6 white.*

```
I tried trial solution.

3 red 2 black = rrr bb for 3 bucket.
rrr
rrb
rbb

If it is 4 red, there will be no difference.
rrr
rrb
rbb

If it is 3 red 3 black, there will be 3.
rrr
rrb
rbb
bbb

I dont know how can i solve.
```

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how many ways there are to make a bouquet of six flowers given the pool of those 6 varieties of flowers...

I think you could first find out how many bouquets she could make if she had an unlimited number (or six in this case) of each variety.  If that were the case she could make $${{6+6-1}\choose 6}=462$$ bouquets.  But any of those bouquets that included 5 or 6 alstromerias would be impossible, since there are only 4 of them.  So subtract out the number of those bouquets that included 6 alstromerias $(1)$ and the number that included 5 alstromerias $(5)$ to get the solution.

$${{6+6-1}\choose 6}-6=456$$

Comment: Can you explain first part little more. I got the second part but. I dont understand 6+6-1

Comment: It is a "stars and bars" problem.  Like, how many 3 scoop ice cream sundaes can you make with 5 flavors.  Or combinations with repeats.  You can search for those on here.  And the number of those combinations is n+k-1 "choose" n.  Again, search this site for stars and bars and you will find better explanations than what i can provide.